# How to make a dynamic button for different screen sizes in CSS?

Tags: html, css, button, dynamic

these [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz8kO.png) should adapt dynamically to my website if it is a tablet or mobile screen size. At the moment it is cropped very ugly as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3obgu.png), but I can't think of a solution.

```
#signup  input {
font-size: 16px;
border: 3px;
border-radius: 5px;
height: 40px;
width: 300px;
text-align: center;}

#signup .button {
font-size: 16px;
padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 300px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #008A74 , #9f0f44);}
```

May it is very easy, but I can't figure it out.
Many thanks in advance!

King regards,
cookiesla

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with your input or .button CSS. Looks like the container (#signup?) is being restricted in width. Try opening dev tools in your browser and inspect computed properties for #signup.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #signup .button ,#signup input {
        width: auto;
    }
}
```